# AS3:: How to handle an issue with Resize Handler

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, resize

At the bottom i show my class `DocObject` code which responds for `MovieClips` location on the `stage` with help of the `stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE,onResizeDoc);` method.

The problem is that when i publish the main.fla file to swf or html, it's not showing any Movie Clips or loaded object until the first Resizie od the window?

Do anyone know, how to handle with this problem?

I only know that the poroblem causes this two lines:

> miniaturki.height = sh;
>
> miniaturki.height = 500;

When I delete those two, the problem disappears.

Here is the `DocObject` class code:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.display.SimpleButton;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageDisplayState;

    public class DocObject extends MovieClip
    {
        public function DocObject():void
        {
            if(stage)
            {
                initialize();
            }
            else
            {
                addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,initialize);
            }
        }
        private function initialize(e:Event = null):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE,initialize);
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE,onResizeDoc);
            resizeMyDoc();
            stage.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, onRemove);
        }
        
        private function onResizeDoc(event:Event = null):void 
        {
            resizeMyDoc();
        }
        
        private function resizeMyDoc():void
        {
            var sw:Number = stage.stageWidth;
            var sh:Number = stage.stageHeight;
            var sBw = sw - 320;
        
            if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN)
            {
                nazwa.x = 0 + 10;
                nazwa.y = sh + 20;
        
                ilosc.x = sw-10;
                ilosc.y = sh + 20;
        
                scrolbar.x = 0;
                scrolbar.y = sh;
                scrolbar.width = sw;
        
                scro.x = scro.x;
                scro.y = sh;
        
                miniaturki.x = miniaturki.x;
                miniaturki.y = 0;
                miniaturki.height = sh;
                miniaturki.scaleX = miniaturki.scaleY;
        
                bcgr.x = 0;
                bcgr.y = 0;
                bcgr.width = sw;
                bcgr.height = sh;
        
                maska1.x = 0;
                maska1.y = 0;
                maska1.width = sw;
                maska1.height = sh;
            }
        
            else
            {
                nazwa.x = 0 + 10;
                nazwa.y = sh / 2 + 200;
        
                ilosc.x = sw-450;
                ilosc.y = sh / 2 + 200;
        
                scrolbar.x = 0;
                scrolbar.y = sh / 2 + 250;
                scrolbar.width = sBw;
        
                scro.x = scro.x;
                scro.y = sh / 2 + 250;
        
                miniaturki.x = miniaturki.x;
                miniaturki.y = sh / 2 - 250;
                miniaturki.height = 500;
                miniaturki.scaleX = miniaturki.scaleY;
        
                bcgr.x = bcgr.x;
                bcgr.y = sh / 2 - 250;
                bcgr.width = sBw;
                bcgr.height = 500;
        
                maska1.x = 0;
                maska1.y = sh / 2 - 250;
                maska1.width = sBw;
                maska1.height = 500;
            }
        }
        
        private function onRemove(e:Event):void
        {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResizeDoc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved it by adding do function `initialize()` this line:  `stage.dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.RESIZE));`